# How to make a round frame with radial gradient with CSS3?

Tags: css, border, gradient, radial-gradients, radial

I need to create a round frame around a transparent center. The frame has a radial gradient from inner to outer border.

The round div is easy with border-radius 50%.

The problem is adding a radial gradient to the border. I tried with border-image, border-color, box-shadow, radial-gradient without any success, while with background-image I didn't manage to have the transparent center.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Enrico

Comment: Have you tried `border-radius: 50%`?

Comment: My bad. I have a round border, but I don't know how to make the radial gradient. I'm going to edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow`

```css
.radial-thinggy {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px rgba(255,69,0,1),
              0 0 20px 20px rgba(255,140,0,1),
              0 0 30px 30px rgba(255,255,0,1);
 }

body {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="radial-thinggy"></div>
```

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks. I tried with box-shadow before posting here but I couldn't make it work properly...

Comment: @LGSon That's great, Thank you.